# Compute cartesian product of two lists without elements at same index

Tags: python, set

I have two lists with the same length, say 3.

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[4,5,6]
```

I want to get Cartesian product of the two, **but** the element at the same position shouldn't be count i.e. :

```
(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5)
```

How shall I do that?

Comment: I just added an answer to your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can nearly directly jot down your 'refined' carthesian product:

```
 ((a[i], b[j]) 
      for i in range(len(a))
      for j in range(len(b))
      if i != j)
```

Comment: This is the clear solution.  In fact, I was about to post essentially the identical thing until I saw you already had :)

Comment: How well does this extend to multiple `list`s, in terms of code size?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: N(len(lists)).  For multiple lists, a clause has to be added, and the condition would have to be altered to `not (i == j or i == k or ...)`.  In case you don't know the number of operands upfront, you would need a helper function.  But probably then you're better off using numpy or the like.

Comment: That's pretty much why I tried to stick with `itertools.product`, yeah. I guess each approach has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 4):

So here's my way to do it use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [4, 5, 6]

spe = set(zip(A, B))
l = [i for i in itertools.product(A, B) if i not in spe]
```

---

From the document of `itertools.product()`:

> `itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)`
> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order.

And `zip()` does *Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.* As the document says.

---

So my code create a set and it has the elements which you don't want, then `itertools.product(A, B)` produces the full list, `if i not in spe` removes the elements which you don't want in that list.

Comment: since you mention `set`... how about `set(product(A, B)) - set(zip(A, B))`?

Comment: come to think of it... since the filtering is based on _values_ instead of indices, this won't work for e.g. `special_product([1,1],[1,1])`.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the product in the normal way, then filter it out:

```
import itertools
A=[1,2,3]
B=[4,5,6]
prod = ((x,y) for x,y in itertools.product(A, B) if A.index(x) != B.index(y))
```

Result:

```
>>> for p in prod:
...     print(p)
...
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
```

`prod` is a generator there, so remember to instead create a comprehension with `prod = [...]` if you plan on using it more than once.

Note that this doesn't work if `A` and `B` contain repeated elements. To solve this, `enumerate` it and discard the items with unwanted indices:

```
prod = (item for idx,item in enumerate((x,y) for x,y in itertools.product(A, B)) if idx%(len(A)))
```

Result:

```
>>> for p in prod:
...     print(p)
...
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 5)
(3, 6)
```

Comment: What happens for `A=[1, 1, 1] x B=[2, 2, 2]`?  "Return the index in the list of _the first_ item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.
"

Comment: Two problems:  (1) The test inside the comprehension adds a factor of n to the performance, since it will search both lists for each and every result item.  Instead of O(n^2), it will be O(n^3).  And (2) It will fail if either list contains a duplicate element.  Consider A=[1,1] and B=[2,3].  The result should be [(1,3), (1,2)], but instead this will incorrectly give [(!,3), (1,2)].

Comment: Then it would break, but the question didn't specify repeated elements.

Comment: I'll fix it, though. :)

Comment: The values in the lists should have no effect on the selection process.  If two values happen to be the same in one of the lists, then the corresponding values in the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approaches. Since the cartesian product is a set, I will provide my answer as a set of tuples:

#### Using a set comprehension

```
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[4,5,6]
>>> {(a, b) for i, a in enumerate(A) for j, b in enumerate(B) if i != j}
{(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5)}
```

I use `enumerate(l)` in order to have a tuple `(index, element)` at each iteration in which `index` is the index of each `element` of `l`.

#### Using itertools

```
>>> import itertools
>>> {(a, b) for a, b in itertools.product(A, B) if A.index(a) != B.index(b)}
{(1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any indexing on the lists nor any calculation based on the length of the lists, using plain enumerate

```
>>> g=((a,b) for pa,a in enumerate(A) for pb,b in enumerate(B) if pa!=pb)
>>> for t in g: print(t)
... 
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `list A` and iterate `list B` for each value of `list A`. If index of both list differs, you can print out the combination of elements from both lists.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
                if i != j:
                        print '(',A[i],B[j],')'


( 1 5 )
( 1 6 )
( 2 4 )
( 2 6 )
( 3 4 )
( 3 5 )
```

Comment: It's easier to understand this answer for a beginner.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Updated